# Java - problems with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)

Tags: java, printing, runtime, exec, notepad

I have a small little program, that uses exec("notepad /P print.txt") to print a text file. The problem, is that if it runs once, runs ok, but if I use while(true) or run it in a loop, the printer doesn't print - so Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad /P print.txt"); isn't executed (right).
Where is the problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: Have you ever test it on the console by executing the same command?  I have no printer and I can see multiple popups opened for me. There might be a printer menu behaviour that forces it to be opened at once in a time. You might shut it down before executing next.

Comment: Add code to show a minimum reproducable example, this may help with finding an answer.